# Fade in burger menu on scroll for desktop

Tags: jquery, css

I want the mobile hamburger menu to fade in on desktop screen sizes after scrolling down the page. I have this this working except when closing the mobile menu with the "x", The burger menu is then displaying on top of the regular menu at the top of the page.  I'd like it to revert to how it is on load.

Here is the test site:

https://josh-unger-4lts.squarespace.com

The code below is what I have tried so far:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
 if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
   $(".Header.Header--top").addClass("change");
 } else {

$(".Header.Header--top").removeClass("change");
 }
 });
 });  
 </script>

 <script>
$(function() {
 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
 if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
$(".Mobile.loaded").addClass("burger");
} else {


$(".Mobile.loaded").removeClass("burger");
 }
 });
  });  
 </script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".close-icon").click(function(){
  $(".Mobile.loaded").addClass("change");
  });
   });
    </script>
```

The CSS for the change and expand:

```
   .change {display:none;}

     .burger {display: block;
     position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
    z-index: 1001;
      }

      .expand {display:block !important;}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML to the question, not just a link to your site. Once you fix your site, this question will become irrelevant and will not help future users.

Comment: Wow, your website is cool. This is what we see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLr6P.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the code in your website and I found this snippet which you didn't mention in your question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Mobile-bar-menu").click(function(){
        $(".Mobile.loaded").addClass("expand");
    });
});
```

This (when the burger is clicked) adds the *expand* class to the *.Mobile.loaded* tag which forces showing it. This tag includes both the burger button and the mobile menu. So adding the *expand* class is necessary to show the mobile menu, but you're not removing the class after the mobile menu is closed.

So, what you need to do is to remove the *expand* class when the 'X' button is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Mobile-overlay-close").click(function(){
        $(".Mobile.loaded").removeClass("expand");
    });
});
```

**Note:** this is a workaround, there are many things that should be restructured in your code.

Also in your post, change the **.com3** in the website link to **.com** to make it accessible, and post all relevant code in the question so that others can benefit as well.